# How to uninstall xcode3 from Lion 10.7?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, osx-lion, xcode3.2

I have just bought a macbook air 11" with Lion 10.7. I installed xcode 3.2.5 on it. But its not working. Xcode is installed, consuming much space but I cannot see it in applications. Somewhere I heard that xcode 3 will not work on Lion 10.7, only xcode 4 is compatible on this os. Is it really true? I tried removing xcode 3 but efforts go worthless. What should I do to uninstall it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Xcode, you want to use scripts provided with Xcode to remove it completely. Open a terminal window and invoke `/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools`. Alternatively, you can just drag the Developer folder to the trash, but I don't think that removes *everything* that gets installed by the installer.

And no, Xcode3.2 won't work (entirely right) under Lion. You need Xcode4, v4.2 being the most recent with the iOS5 SDK. And if you want to submit anything to Apple, you'll need 4.2 (i.e. the latest released tools) anyway, at this point.

Comment: Oh, learned something new today, didn't know that Xcode 3 doesn't work well under Lion. Wanted to mention that you can upgrade to / install Xcode 4, then remove Xcode 3 if you want. You don't have to remove it 1st, according to this article anyways: http://www.chrisk.de/blog/2011/03/how-to-upgrade-to-xcode-4-or-uninstall-xcode-3/

Answer (score 0):

I would use this utility. It's always worked better than the traditional way to "unistall" applications form OSX

http://appzapper.com/

The reviews have always been good for this app.

Comment: Xcode is special. I wouldn't use something like appzapper in this particular case...

Comment: if appzapper does not work for xcode then should I use the traditional way to uninstall it as written by Mark?